# Programmatically switch to CompleteWizardStep in CreateUserWizard control

Tags: c#, asp.net-membership, createuserwizard

How do I programmatically switch to the `asp:CompleteWizardStep` step in the `OnCreatingUser` event in the `asp:CreateUserWizard` control?

ASP.NET web form

```
<asp:CreateUserWizard ID="MyCreateUserWizard" runat="server" OnCreatingUser="MyCreateUserWizard_CreatingUser">
    <WizardSteps>
        <asp:CreateUserWizardStep ID="CreateUserStep1" runat="server">
            <!-- code here -->
        </asp:CreateUserWizardStep>
        <asp:CompleteWizardStep ID="CompleteWizardStep" runat="server">
            <!-- code here -->
        </asp:CompleteWizardStep>
    </WizardSteps>
</asp:CreatedWizardStep>
```

Code behind

```
protected void MyCreateUserWizard_CreatingUser(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //retrieve username, password and email

    Membership.CreateUser(username, password, email);

    //would like to display the CompleteWizardStpe here

}
```

Comment: What does it do instead, and why are you manually creating a user instead of allowing the control to do it for you?

Comment: @Greg - It goes to the `asp:CreateUserWizardStep` view with the usename and e-mail control filled in with the input from the user.  It does not show the `asp:CompleteWizardStep` view at all.  Even if I do not programmatically call the `Membership.CreateUser` method.

Comment: @Greg - I remove the `OnCreatingUser` event and it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void CreateUserWizard1_CreatingUser(object sender, LoginCancelEventArgs e)
{
    CreateUserWizard1.MoveTo(CompleteWizardStep1);
}
```

Comment: @Sky Sanders - Calling the `MoveTo` did not solve the problem.

Comment: if you want to completely bypass the built-in functionality of the control, set `e.Cancel = true;` and then MoveTo. The control will no longer create a user or email them.

Comment: @Greg - Didn't not work.  I cast a local variable to a `LoginCancelEventArgs` object using the `e` object and it did not display the asp:CompleteWizardStep control.

Comment: @Greg, good catch. @Michael? cast a local variable? just set e.Cancel=true; and the call MoveTo. That should work just fine.

Comment: I was still using the original method signature from my code example with the `EventsArgs` input parameters.  I changed the signature to your example and it still do not work.

Answer (score 0):

I just recreated your solution in VS2008 / .net 3.5 using the empty OnCreatingUser event handler and it "works on my computer". So, what's different that could be causing this problem?

aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1._Default"
    Trace="false" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:CreateUserWizard ID="CreateUserWizard1" runat="server" OnCreatingUser="CreateUserWizard1_CreatingUser">
        <WizardSteps>
            <asp:CreateUserWizardStep ID="CreateUserWizardStep1" runat="server">
            </asp:CreateUserWizardStep>
            <asp:CompleteWizardStep ID="CompleteWizardStep1" runat="server">
            </asp:CompleteWizardStep>
        </WizardSteps>
    </asp:CreateUserWizard>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Code-behind:

```
namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void CreateUserWizard1_CreatingUser(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.LoginCancelEventArgs e)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms" />
```

Video of it working: http://www.screentoaster.com/watch/stWEJSR0ZIR19YRVleWV9QXlJX

Comment: @Greg - I can not watch the video because it is blocked by my WebSense at work.  I will watch it when I get home.

Comment: @Greg - I am using a web site project model instead of a web application project model.  This should not make a difference.

Comment: A developer behind WebSense is a crime. :(